# Create small page to display content of the table with Symfony and Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am trying to create simple page to display content of the table (customer: id, first_name, last_name) with Symfony + doctrine.
I created GS\OrderBundle\Entity\Customer with columns and getters/setters. Created route for it. I want to create a view , something like:

```
<table>
        {% for c in form %}
        {% set id = c.get('value') %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ form_widget(c) }}</td>
            <td>{{ c[id].firstName }}</td>
            <td>{{ c[id].lastName }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

and Controller to pass the values from the customer table to this view. I am trying something like:

```
namespace GS\OrderBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use GS\OrderBundle\Entity\Customer;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class CustomerListController extends Controller
{
    public function listAction()
    {


        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('GSOrderBundle:Customer');
        $customer = $repository->findAll();

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($customer)->getForm();





        return $this->render(
            'customerTable.html.twig',
            array('form' => $form->createView())
        );

        return new Response($names);
    }
}
```

On the symfony website I found only examples with setting data or outputing single row data. Could you please provide any simple example how to display content of the table in the view?

Comment: You have several issues with your code:

1. Two return statements
2. Creating a form from an array of customers rather than a single entity
3. Not using variable names that you have set in the template

Comment: I am sure that you are 100% right. If I wouldn't have issues I wouldn't ask :)

Comment: Sorry, I pressed enter by mistake :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues with your code:

1. Two return statements
2. Creating a form from an array of customers rather than a single
   entity
3. Not using variable names that you have set in the template

Here is what your view might look like:

```
    <table>
    {% for c in customers %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ c.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ c.firstName }}</td>
            <td>{{ c.lastName }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

And that's a controller that should do the trick for you:

```
    class CustomerListController extends Controller
    {
        public function listAction()
        {

            $repository = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository('GSOrderBundle:Customer');
            $customers = $repository->findAll();

            return $this->render(
                'customerTable.html.twig',
                array('customers' => $customers)
            );
        }
    }
```